# Using lupdate tool

Tags: qt

I'm using Qt 4.7.1 on window vista.I want to make my qt application to be translatable.
How can I use the Lupdate tool to generate .ts files? 
From where I can run it from Qt creator or Qt linguist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google told me this:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/linguist-manager.html

Comment: I already read it and understood what's should be done but the problem is how not what.I want to know how to run the lupdate tool .. from which menu i can find it??

Comment: I know it's old, but this is a good example of why link-only answers are bad

Answer (score 1):

> C:\Qt\4.7.4\bin

or where ever your QT files are found, just check the bin folder.